# Trouble creating a stored procedure that adds columns to any table I specify

Tags: mysql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to make a procedure that allows me to just specify a table and the procedure will automatically add two columns to that table.

```
create proc addAuditFeild (@table_name nvarchar(50))
as
    if OBJECT_ID (@table_name, ''U'') is not null
    begin
        alter table @table_name
        add moduser varchar(50),
            moddate datetime
    end
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried using a exec and it still didn't work. I get scalr variable was not defined in my exec.

```
exec('alter proc addAuditFeild (@table_name nvarchar(50))
as
    if OBJECT_ID (@table_name, ''U'') is not null
    begin
        alter table ' + @table_name + '
        add moduser varchar(50),
            moddate datetime
    end')
```

How would you create a procedure that can add columns to any table you specify in the parameters?

Comment: And the question/problem is...?

Comment: how would you create a procedure that can add columns to any table you specify in the parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this.....

```
ALTER PROCEDURE addAuditFeild 
@table_name SYSNAME
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

  -- check first if the table exists
  IF (OBJECT_ID (@table_name, 'U') IS NOT NULL)
   BEGIN

       -- then check if column "moduser" already exist if not then add one
       IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.tables t 
                      INNER JOIN sys.columns c on t.object_id = c.object_id
                      WHERE t.name = @table_name
                      AND c.name = 'moduser')
        BEGIN
         SET @Sql = N' ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@table_name)
                  + N' ADD moduser varchar(50)'

           exec sp_executesql @Sql
        END

       -- then check if column "moddate" already exist if not then add one
       IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.tables t 
                      INNER JOIN sys.columns c on t.object_id = c.object_id
                      WHERE t.name = @table_name
                      AND c.name = 'moddate')
        BEGIN
         SET @Sql = N' ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@table_name)
                  + N' ADD moddate datetime'

           exec sp_executesql @Sql
        END
   END
END
```

### Edit

To handle Schema issue do the following ....

```
ALTER PROCEDURE addAuditFeild 
  @table_name SYSNAME
 ,@Schem_Name SYSNAME
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

  IF (OBJECT_ID (QUOTENAME(@Schem_Name)+ '.' + QUOTENAME(@table_name), 'U') IS NOT NULL)
   BEGIN
       IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.tables t 
                   INNER JOIN sys.columns c on t.object_id = c.object_id
                   INNER JOIN sys.schemas s on t.schema_id = s.schema_id
                   WHERE t.name = @table_name
                    AND  s.name = @Schem_Name
                    AND c.name = 'moduser')
        BEGIN
         SET @Sql = N' ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@Schem_Name)+ '.' + QUOTENAME(@table_name)
                     + N' add moduser varchar(50)'

           exec sp_executesql @Sql
        END

       IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.tables t 
                   INNER JOIN sys.columns c on t.object_id = c.object_id
                   INNER JOIN sys.schemas s on t.schema_id = s.schema_id
                   WHERE t.name = @table_name
                    AND  s.name = @Schem_Name
                    AND c.name = 'moddate')
        BEGIN
         SET @Sql = N' ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@Schem_Name)+ '.' + QUOTENAME(@table_name)
                     + N' add moddate datetime'

           exec sp_executesql @Sql
        END
   END
END
```

Comment: when i tried this and called the procedure like this addAuditfeild Employees it did not find employees and if i tried to put HR.Employees i got an error

Comment: ok in that case you will also need to take schema into consideration. Make your stored procedure accept another parameter `"Schema"` In object_id use Schema and table name. in column checks in not exist check also join to sys.schemas on schema_id where schema.name = @Schema etc .

Comment: @AndrewVGaming I have edited my answer to handle schema issue.

Comment: my teacher helped me fix it i made table_name a varchar and took out quote name and that fixed the problem i just imputed 'HR.employees' as a parameter thanks for the help your amazing.

Comment: @AndrewVGaming You need a better teacher :( your teacher just sugar coated the problem didnt really fix it. see my edit and this should fix the issue.